# Does getBoundingClientRect().width and height includes paddings and borders of element?

Tags: javascript

Does `getBoundingClientRect().width` and `height` properties, while returning values include paddings and borders of element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lp2hpaz/ — you can test it for yourself.

Comment: Yes things like this can be confusing; that's why in my Fiddle I set up the element with huge borders and padding so that it would be obvious without me having to do the math accurately :)

Comment: @RoseCrime I think you should consider my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622682/2779871

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default it returns `width+padding+border` **Why?.**

Because it's relative to the `box-sizing` CSS property, Which can have two values:

1. `content-box` *(default value)*
2. `border-box`

---

> **content-box:** includes only the content. Border, padding and margin are not included.

This means when you set a width, That width is set to the content only then you add the padding and border.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('p').getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
p {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>The console should log 324px because the width is 300px<br> padding is 10px left 10px right <br> border is 2px left 2px right<br> sums up to 300+10+10+2+2 = 324</p>
```

---

> **border-box:** includes content, padding and border. margin is not included.

This means padding and border will be calculated within the defined width.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('p').getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>console should log 300px Because padding's width and border's width have been calculated wihtin the specified width in the CSS</p>
```

**Note:** Height is not affected, But the same rules are applied to it too.

Comment: Awesome point , didn't even thought it might depend from box-sizing.
Great answer :)

Comment: simple testing in the Dev console will give you the answer, try to use it more. Happy to help :)

Comment: If you want to use `box-sizing: border-box;` and not count border you can use `box-shadow` as a visual substitute.

Comment: It should also be noted that `element.clientWidth` will get you the inner width (including padding), and `element.offsetWidth` will get you the total width (all-inclusive) - same for height obviously. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

Comment: @ZohirSalak I think your answer is a bit misleading when you state that **by default** it returns width+padding+border. It **always** return width+padding+border. Only the behavior of `width` and `height` are affected by `box-sizing` rules.

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph What you said is exactly what the answer states maybe phrased differently, I read your comment many times and i still don't understand what's misleading.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I think it can be confusing for people because "width" is a constrain (a CSS rule) which behavior can change with the `box-sizing` rule as we know, while "content width" is an attribute of the [CSS box model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#box-model). Beginners tend to conflate the two. `getBoundingClientRect` will always return the [border box](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#valdef-box-border-box), while the computed `width` style constrain might change depending on box-sizing. I've illustrated this in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622682/2779871.

Comment: @ZohirSalak The author question was exactly "Does getBoundingClientRect().width and height includes paddings and borders of element?", and the answer is yes.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I have reworded my answer, I thinks it makes a better job at distinguishing style width and content width.

Comment: I wonder hot to get the margin. All the SO answers tell to use the `getComputedStyle` but it's wrong -- it's returning `0px` if it's auto, while when you inspect the element in browser devtools you see the brown margin that is not 0. It's funny to read things like this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381328#c5 saying that "getcomputed style shouldn't return computed style". How do I get it then?

Comment: @Nakilon i think you should post a question

Answer (score 16):

### TLDR;

It will always return dimensions of the *border box* (green box bellow), which contains the *content area*, *padding area* and *border area*, as defined in the [CSS Box Model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#box-model).

[image: CSS Box Model]

### The width style

However, one must not conflate *content width* (a property of the element layout) and *style width* (a constraint on the element layout, `width: xxx;` rules) which are very distinct things. The `box-sizing` will only affect whether the *style width* constraint should include the *border* and *padding*, or not.

### Demonstration by example

In this first snippet, we are using `box-sizing: border-box` rule so that *style width == boder + padding + content width*. The result of `getBoundingClientRect().width` is `140`, and it equals *style width*.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
console.log('getBoundingClientRect().width =', x.getBoundingClientRect().width);
console.log('getComputedStyle(x).width =', getComputedStyle(x).width);
```

```css
#x {
  border: 20px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id=x>Border Box</div>
```

In the second snippet, we are using `box-sizing: content-box` rule so that *style width == content width*. The result of `getBoundingClientRect().width` is still `140` **because the sum** of *border* + *padding* + *content width* **has not changed**, only *style width* has changed.

```js
var y = document.getElementById("y");
console.log('y.getBoundingClientRect().width =', y.getBoundingClientRect().width);
console.log('getComputedStyle(y).width =', getComputedStyle(y).width);
```

```css
#y {
  border: 20px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div id=y>Content Box</div>
```

### References

- [MDN | Introduction to the CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)
- [CSSWG | CSS2 (Box Model)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#box-model)
- [MDN | Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)